# ADF Oracle : How to increase the size width of each bar in BarGraph

Tags: oracle, bar-chart, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I use the same as on this web [BarGraph sample](http://adfwithejb.blogspot.co.id/2013/01/programmatically-creation-of-bar-graph.html) . How to change the width of **4 bar** size in ADF Oracle?
[image: asdaf]

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your barGraph Component

```
 <dvt:seriesSet defaultLineWidth="2">
    <dvt:series/>
 </dvt:seriesSet>
```

defaultLineWidth attribute will change the bar widths. Play around with it until you get the desired width.

-Sid